# WiFi conflicting with local mysql connection (Java/Spring)

Tags: java, mysql, macos, spring, hibernate

I'm using java/spring to connect to a local mysql database and run some integration tests.  Sometimes I get Hibernate errors saying that a connection cannot be established.  I've noticed this only happens when WiFi is turned on.   If I turn off WiFi, and plug in an ethernet cable, the connection established just fine and all integration tasks pass.

I found sources for this issue regarding PHP, where localhost and 127.0.0.1 are treated differently (one uses TCP, while the other uses the local socket), but none of those solutions helped.   I have ensured that IPV6 is disabled and the only parameters in the /etc/hosts file is "127.0.0.1 localhost"

Also, simply running mysql from the command line connects just fine, regardless of whether i use

```
mysql -u<username> -p -h127.0.0.1 //or
mysql -u<username> -p -hlocalhost
```

Does anyone have any idea why my WiFi connection is preventing me from connecting to my local DB from spring?

Comment: 1) I do not think it should go there, having a connection issue is for serverfault or superuser. That the connection is for mysql or for surfing the web is not that relevant. 2) Windows has a nice "feature" where it deactivates the TCP stack if no cable is connected. Of course it should not fire if you are connected to the WiFi, are you sure the WiFi is really on when you do the tests (try connecting somewhere)? That feature can be deactivated in the windows registry

Comment: 3) also check for firewalls, maybe there are different settings for the different networks.

Comment: If I may respond to your points:   1)  I agree that this is perhaps a serverfault style issue, but I'm developing in spring using a local copy of mysql, which makes me think it could be a software configuration issue.  2) Not windows, Mac OSX 10.8 3)  Corporate network.  I don't have control over the outgoing connections, but they filter through the same outgoing point.   Also, should firewalls matter if I'm connecting to localhost?

Comment: By 3) I meant your computer firewall, either from the OS or installed programs.

Comment: I turned off the firewall completely, and it did not make a difference.

Comment: My hypothesis: You keep losing your IP address on the wifi.  You don't lose your connection, you simply get a different IP address.  Depending on how you connect to mysql, you may be using an IP that you have allowed in mysql's settings, or you may sometimes be inadvertently connecting via a second IP.  My company's network has auto-load-balancing.  maybe something similar is happening there

Comment: Russell,  I think this may be a good hypothesis.  There are several access points throughout the building, and IPs are not consistant when assigned from different APs.   Any idea how to fix it though?